# Handle duplicate code in concrete implementations of an interface in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working on a spring boot application, where I have an interface `I` as follows:

```
public interface I {

   String getType();

   void f1();

}
```

There are two classes implementing interface `I` as follows:

```
@Component
class A implements I {
   
    private final MyRepo1 myRepo1;
    private final Helper helper;

    public A(MyRepo1 myRepo1, Helper helper) {
       this.myRepo1 = myRepo1;
       this.helper = helper;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "type1";
    }

    @Override
    public void f1(String type) {
        int response = helper.f1(type);
        if(response != -1) {
           return;
        }
        //Add type1 specific handling here
    }
 }
```

One more class B implementing interface I as follows:

```
@Component
class B implements I {
    private final MyRepo2 myRepo2;
    private final Helper helper;

    public B(MyRepo2 myRepo2, Helper helper) {
       this.myRepo2 = myRepo2;
       this.helper = helper;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "type2";
    }

    @Override
    public void f1(String type) {
        int response = helper.f1(type);
        if(response != -1) {
           return;
        }
        //Add type2 specific handling here
    }
}
```

Helper is as follows:

```
@Component
class Helper {

    public int f1(String type) {
      ...
    }
}
```

I have a factory class as follows, that is used to fetch an object of the appropriate type:

```
@Component
public class ServiceFactory {

  private final Map<String, I>
      typeToClassMap = new HashMap<>();

  public ServiceFactory(List<I> components) {
      for(I component : components) {
          typeToClassMap.put(component.getType(), component);
      }
  }
}
```

This `ServiceFactory` is basically used to get objects according to the type.

Now, the problem is, here for sake of simplicity I have just shown two classes implementing the interface. But actually, I have a lot more classes than this, implementing the interface `I`.

Some of the classes may have the same implementation of `f1()`, resulting in duplicate code.

I cannot make `f1()` as the default method in interface `I` as this requires the dependent bean.

I cannot understand what is the best way to handle this.

Could anyone please help here?

Comment: You could implement `f1` in an abstract class

Comment: @codeflush.dev, thanks for your response. Do you mean each bean should implement the interface I and extend an abstract class A, where I can put the common implementation of `f1()` ?

Comment: You could implement the common implementation of `f1()` in an abstract class, which you extend in all the classes that want to use that implementation